Use checkbox, text field, dropdown list and file upload to get data on the same page in Flask
I am absolutely new to Flask, only created static web-pages so far.
I have a function that need to take all of these inputs at the same time. The function will process an  uploaded audio file (automatic speech recognition) and output text on the user screen. The processing type depending on the other inputs (checkboxes etc.). The produced text can be displayed on the same page below or on another page opened by the app.
It should be accessible via Internet so I need a web-form. Flask is the framework used at the platform.
I found examples for using any of these elements separately, but can't make them all work together.
